# Semantic Mediawiki and properties in template

Tags: mediawiki, semantics, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

I have the following construction in the template to check whether attributes are full

```
{{#if:{{{typeip|}}}|'''Type IP:'''{{{typeip}}}|<big>'''Type IP:'''</big><span style="color: red">not filled in</span>}}
```

I want the typyap attribute to be a property so that I can find it by semantic search or by using a query via the #ask function.

I tried the following construction

```
{{#if:[[typeip::{{{typeip|}}}]]|'''Type IP:'''{{{typeip}}}|<big>'''Type IP:'''</big><span style="color: red">not filled in</span>}}
```

But it doesn't work. The #asc function returns an empty request and the type ip property page is empty. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? I performed reindexing using a service script rebuildData.php But that doesn't help either. I tried to insert the property in various other places in the template, but it doesn't work either. The template is filled in using the form.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it doesn't work. You invoke the `{{#if:}}` parser function incorrectly.

Its parametres are:

1. the condition,
2. the value returned if the first parametre does not evaluate to an empty string or whitespace,
3. the value returned if the first parametre is empty.

Therefore the semantic annotation should be in the second parametre, not the first:

```
{{#if:{{{typeip|}}}
| '''Type IP:''' [[typeip::{{{typeip}}}]]
| <big>'''Type IP:'''</big><span style="color: red">not filled in</span>
}}
```

`{{{typeip}}}` should be bare text without any wiki formatting. If you *must* pass wikitext to it to convert wikilinks into semantic annotations setting properties of the type *Page*, the simplest way will be as follows:

- Install [Scribunto](https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto),
- create `Module:Inject` with the following content:

```lua
return {
    property = function (frame)
        local wikitext, property = frame.args[1], frame.args[2]
        local annotation = mw.ustring.gsub (
            wikitext,
            '%[%[([^|%]]+)(|[^%]]*)?%]%]',
            '[[' .. property .. '::%1%2]]'
        )
        return annotation
    end
}
```

- put the following in your template:

```
{{#invoke:Inject|property|{{{typeip|}}}|typeip}}
```

The template will convert any wikilinks in `{{{typeip}}}` like `[[A]]` or `[[B|C]]` into semantic annotations like `[[typeip::A]]` or `[[typeip::B|C]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

It worked! But only for fields where the data type is either text, date, or number. It doesn't work with fields that link to other pages for some reason. 

For example, I have a value field in which a form is selected from a list of pages in a different category. And it doesn't work for this field. 

Moreover, this field is displayed incorrectly in the template if I add a property to it. 

Don't know what to do in this situation?

Comment: You mean, if the template parametre is a wikilink like `[[Page]]`, then the annotation doesn't work? If so, it shouldn't. Either pass the bare `Page` to the template, or process the parametre with a regular expression--you will need either a MediaWiki extension that enables regular expressions, or Lua.

Comment: Yes! That's what I mean. I have an extension ParserFunctions. Is it enough? Only I honestly have no idea how to set the property via a regular expression in this case. Can you give an example please?

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! I will deal with all this! I couldn't have done it without you!